# if (Time 12:00 = DateTime.Now) как правильно сделать?

Tags: c#, datetime

есть программа на c#, в ней, например, раз в день в 12:00 должно выполняться определенное действие, а в другие часы другое действие.

в 12:00 он не захотел отрабатывать.

как правильно это реализовать?

```
DayToday = new DateTime(daynow1.Year, daynow1.Month, daynow1.Day, 12, 0, 0);              
if (DayToday == DateTime.Now)                            
{    
    Что-то делается    
}    
else    
{    
    Что-то другое делается    
}
```

Comment: когда вызывается этот код?

Comment: код вызывается по таймеру раз в час, но это не важно код отрабатывает только по else, а в 12:00 он должен отработать по if но не хочет

Comment: сделайте условие не на точное время. а на час и ставьте флаг. или вызывайте раз в минуту

Comment: так как вы не гарантируете, что таймер запускается ровно в `00:00` каждого часа, то и проверка может проходить или нет, в зависимости от времени запуска таймера

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var timeNow = DateTime.Now;
if (timeNow.Hour == 12 && timeNow.Minute == 00)
{
}
```

Но этот код не гарантирует выполнение блока *then* в момент времени 12:00, если вызывать его реже одного раза в минуту.